# What should be return type of void* function?

Tags: multithreading, function, types, return, void

I'm learning some multithreading with <pthread.h> lib. I got a problem with a return value from function which I use in: `pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, bar, (void*)i);`

Definition of bar:

```
void *bar(void* thread_id) {
    long t_id;
    t_id = (long)thread_id;
    std::cout << "I am a thread and my Thread ID is: " << t_id << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
        std::cout << "i: " << i << std::endl;

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

What should I return from bar??

Comment: any value. only your code interpret it

Comment: Is that a trick question? The return type of a function returning `void *` is `void *`.

Comment: Ok, but I can't simply write "return*;"